# Python: how to Image.resize in a for loop?

Tags: python, image, resize, pygtk

I am trying to make an for-loop which is run through an list with 4 values:
`16, 32, 64, 128`.

These are the four sizes the script need to resize images to.

This is my full code:

```
def on_btn_resize_clicked(self, widget):
    if len(self.imgOriginal) > 0 and len(self.appRoot) > 0: #check if original-image and app-root is select
        _imgFilename = os.path.splitext(basename(self.imgOriginal))[0] #get filename
        _imgFileExtension = os.path.splitext(basename(self.imgOriginal))[1] # get filextension

        quickly_sizes = [16, 32, 64, 128] #define all sizes, resize to 16x16, 32x32, 64x64, 128x128
        for size in quickly_sizes:
            print size
            im=Image.open(self.imgOriginal)
            im = im.convert("RGB")
            im = im.resize((int(size), int(size)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            im.save(self.appRoot+"/data/media/"+_imgFilename+str(size)+_imgFileExtension)

        widget.set_label("All four images is save!")
        from subprocess import call
        call(["nautilus", self.appRoot+"/data/media/"]) #open/show folder where all files is save
```

The loop is running, but it does not save the images in the folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You don't need to do `int(size)` in the resize and where do `_imgFilename` and `_imgFileExtension` come from?

Comment: Nop! ok I remove int(size).. hmm try see here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1294721/

Comment: Add a print statement to verify where it's saving the files to. I just ran your quickly_sizes loop on a test png and it worked.

Comment: Cool it works :) but I need to close Nautilus/gnome-open first, then open it again.. and then all the images is shown. Or just an 'ls'

Answer (score 0):

The code above works :)

But you need to close Nautilus/gnome-open first, then open it again.. and then all the images is shown. Or just an 'ls'

```
from subprocess import call
call(["nautilus", self.appRoot+"/data/media/"])
```